# Hide databases from cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I have `reseller` with `whm` `panel`

I want to create user for `domain` without having `databases` panel like this picture:

[image]

all other features are ok but i want to hide it from user.
i did a lot of search but i couldn't find any solution thanks for help!

[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=hide%20databases%20from%20cpanel&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

i did this search on google but no result found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide such thing in WHM for a single user but there's work around for that and it is as follows.

Create A Package under your WHM and give it name like "No Database" and with this Package select Database '0' so that this package will not have any database and then create hosting account and under package select 'No Database" Package so the user will have no access to the Database. He will see Databases options show in your picture but when user will try to add database it won't add.

Adding some pictures for your ref.

[image]

[image]